# Promise method of then running before Promise is completed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

In the following example, After the Promise is completed and `aaa` is printed, then only `hello` should be printed. But, it is not happening. Why, as `.then` method runs only after Promise is completed.

```js
function printF(item){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(setTimeout(function(){console.log('aaa')}, 1000)));
}

printF(10).then(res => console.log('hello'));
```

Comment: in the current form of the question the code shown resolves then calls the then method given, I don't think the question asked is possible with any current implementation... perhaps consult the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If because you are resolving your promise immediately i.e. `setTimeout` is called inside of promise, so promise will be resolve immediately triggering `.then` part and then after 1 sec the `setTimeout` code will be executed.

Instead, `resolve` promise after 1 second by taking wrapping the `resolve` inside `setTimeout` as -

```js
function printF(item) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log('aaa')), 1000)
  );
}

printF(10).then(res => console.log('hello'));
```